# PHP loop error message

Tags: php

I am new to php as well as posting php code. SO if there is any information missing please let me know. 
I am trying to have a list of products echo through a foreach loop. I am not sure whether the mistake is just syntax or something bigger than that. 
Here is the error message:

```
Home
Product List

Code Name Version Release Date   
( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tech_support/product_manager/product_list.php on line 15

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  247496  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   0.0024  273008  include( '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tech_support/product_manager/product_list.php' )    ../index.php:20
```

Here's is product_list php.

```
<?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>

    <h1>Product List</h1>

        <!-- display a table of products -->
        <h2><?php echo $products; ?></h2>

            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Version</th>
                 <th>Release Date</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?> //<-----line 15
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $product['product_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
                <td class="right"><?php echo $product['version']; ?></td>
                <td><form action="." method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id"
                           value="<?php echo $product['releaseDate']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                </form></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <p><a href="?action=show_add_form">Add Product</a></p>


<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

Heres the code I have in my index folder.

```
<?php
require('../model/database.php');
require('../model/product_db.php');

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if ($action === NULL) {
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
    if ($action === NULL) {
        $action = 'list_products';
    }
}

 if ($action == 'list_products') {
    $product_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'product_id', 
            FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); 
    if ($product_id == NULL || $product_id == FALSE) {
        $product_id = 1;
    }
  $products = get_product($product_id);
    include('product_list.php');    
}
 else if ($action == 'show_add_form') {
    $product = get_product($product_id);
    include('product_add.php');    
.......
```

Just in case here is my database functions

```
<?php


function get_product($product_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM products
              WHERE productCode = :product_id';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(":product_id", $product_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $products = $statement->fetch();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $products;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like `$products` may be an object, not an array?

Answer (score 0):

If  `$products` is an object you can try to typecast it before use it in loop like this: 
 
 `$array =  (array) $yourObject;`

Answer (score 0):

as looking into:

[PDO Fetch](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php)

it returns an array of the data, not an object as expected.

so, try to

```
var_dump( $products );
```

to take a look what it really is...an object or an array.

hope that helps.

Comment: Do I need to declare that as a function then call it? Or do I add that line (var_dump) somewhere specific?

Comment: add the var_dump( $products ); right after where $products is filled.